# fraction of volume of a rectilinear grid cell within some radius of the origin

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, simulation

I have a sphere (radius R) on a rectilinear grid. Some cells intersect the edge of that sphere, call them 'edge cells'. Designate a given cell by indices [i,j,k] which refer to the lowest-index vertex of that cell (i.e. the inner-most cell, in the [+x,+y,+z] octant would be designated as [0,0,0]). For any given 'edge cell', how can I calculate what fraction of its volume is within the sphere of radius R?

In this figure, the purple surface is the surface of the sphere passing through some arbitrary cell, with origin [x0,y0,z0]. I want to know what fraction of the cell's volume is within this surface.

[image]

I think 'edge cells' can be calculated by finding the cells whose vertex [i,j,k] is at a radius R.

I think there should be an analytic formula to calculate the volume fraction, but I can't figure out how to setup the integral. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems like a calculus question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus and a nasty one at that

Comment: The closest I found on the web is the sphere segment. But it is far
from the mark. I doubt you can find a single formula for it, and that
may be why you do not know how to set up the integral. The problem is
that you have several different cases, which should give different
formulae. Your drawing is the simplest one. But, for example, the
upper blue corner of the intersection could be on the upper edge of
the left side of the cube. A smallish sphere can cause strange cases. Where is the
sphere center? The sphere segment gives you an idea of the greater
complexity of your problem,

Comment: Cells are unlikely to have a vertex at radius R. But there are ways of identifying them rather quickly. I doubt this is your main worry.